# How to disable caching for all WebApi responses in order to avoid IE using (from cache) responses

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-caching

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web Api controller:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestScenariosController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("v2")]
    public ActionResult<List<TestScenarioItem>> GetAll()
    {
        var entities = _dbContext.TestScenarios.AsNoTracking().Select(e => new TestScenarioItem
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name,
            Description = e.Description,
        }).ToList();

        return entities;
    }
}
```

When I query this action from angular app using `@angular/common/http`:

```
this.http.get<TestScenarioItem[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/TestScenarios/v2`);
```

In IE11, I only get the cached result.

**How do I disable cache for all web api responses?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add [`ResponseCacheAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.responsecacheattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to the controller, like this:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
public class TestScenariosController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can add `ResponseCacheAttribute` as a global filter, like this:

```
services
    .AddMvc(o =>
    {
        o.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute { NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None });
    });
```

This disables all caching for MVC requests and can be overridden per controller/action by applying `ResponseCacheAttribute` again to the desired controller/action.

See [ResponseCache attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2#responsecache-attribute) in the docs for more information.

Comment: odd enough I did exactly this in a .net 6 asp.net app and I am still not receiving the correct caching related response headers from api controllers