# What is equivalent of ResponseCacheFilter(NameSpace- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal) In .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.0

Can anyone please help me to transform below code from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(
            new ResponseCacheFilter(
                new CacheProfile { NoStore = true },
                LoggerFactory));
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: What error are you getting?  It may be failing due to TLS 1.0/1.1 being obsoleted in June.  Also see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same code as you and were migrating from 2.1 to 3.1.
At last I found this SO answer that guided me in the right direction.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55686482/537842

```cs
services
    .AddMvc(o =>
    {
        o.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute { NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None });
    });
```

So, just change `ResponseCacheFilter` to `ResponseCacheAttribute` and drop the `LoggerFactory` and you should be good to go!